# Whats the difference between these two?

Tags: css

could you help me with this, know its a stupid question I'm this a new ballgame for me?         .................................................

```
  #menubutton ul .item {
              display: none; 
              right: 70px; 
              }  

  .item {  
                display: block;
                border: 1px solid white;
                background-color: black;
                width: 100px;
                height: 20px;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 19px;
            }




 <div id="menubutton">
    <ul>
      <li class="button">
          <div id="line"></div>
          <div id="line"></div>
          <div id="line"></div>
      </li>
      <li class="oneitem"></li>
      <li class="item" ><a href="#">#</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">#</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">#</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">#</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">#</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hugh, What are the `two` things here?

Comment: I don't see two distinct things to compare...?

Comment: sorry wasn't very specific at all. got an answer so its all good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .item CSS tag will apply to anything with the class of 'item', regardless of hierarchy or element type. The #menubutton ul .item is narrowing the selector down to ul elements with a class of .item within a parent with id of 'menubutton'.

Comment: And will "<li class="item" ><a href="#">#</a></li>"  take the more specific selector ( i.e the #menubutton ul .item selector)  rather than the .item  by the default even though both apply to it?

Comment: Well, this is where things start to get a little crazy in the CSS world. Specificity is a very complicated subject. I believe I can answer your question by saying that any style attributes that get applied to the #menubutton ul .item will take precedence over the .list class style attributes. The reason is the leading ID, which has higher specificity, only trumped by a style attribute in the HTML. The best thing to do is write some CSS and HTML and open your browser's devtools and inspect elements to see what happens; you can change style attributes in your browser to see what the effect is.